# Sed - convert negative to positive numbers

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to convert all negative numbers to positive numbers and have so far come up with this

```
echo "-32 45 -45 -72" | sed -re 's/\-([0-9])([0-9])\ /\1\2/p'
```

but it is not working as it outputs:

3245 -45 -72

I thought by using \1\2 I would have got the positive number back ?

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What about just `sed 's/-//g'` ?

Answer (score 12):

Why not just remove the -'s?

```
[root@vm ~]# echo "-32 45 -45 -72" | sed 's/-//g'
32 45 45 72
```

Comment: @frodo Can you accept any of the answer.
Did you face any problem with this answer

Answer (score 4):

My first thought is not using sed, if you don't have to. awk can understand that they're numbers and convert them thusly:

```
echo "-32 45 -45 -72" | awk -vRS=" " -vORS=" " '{ print ($1 < 0) ? ($1 * -1) : $1 }'
```

-vRS sets the "record separator" to a space, and -vORS sets the "output record separator" to a space. Then it simply checks each value, sees if it's less than 0, and multiplies it by -1 if it is, and if it's not, just prints the number.

In my opinion, if you don't *have* to use sed, this is more "correct," since it treats numbers like numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
 echo "-32 45 -45 -72" | sed 's/-\([0-9]\+\)/\1/g'
```

Reason why your regex is failing is

1. Your only doing a single substitution (no `g`)
2. Your replacement has no space at the end.
3. The last number has no space following so it will always fail.

This would work too but less elegantly (and only for 2 digit numbers):

```
 echo "-32 45 -45 -72" | sed -rn 's/-([0-9])([0-9])(\s?)/\1\2\3/gp'
```

Of course for this example only:

```
 echo "-32 45 -45 -72" | tr -d '-'
```

Comment: thanks potong - could you explain how the \'s work in this part of your code:  \([0-9]\+\)   .... do they escape the values after them ?

Comment: @frodo I've written the regex without using the `-r` switch (extended regular expression), so in order for the parens to act as grouping meta characters, they have to be escaped i.e. `sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/.../'` would be written `sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)/.../'` N.B. the `+` has to be escaped too.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with numbers as with a string of characters. More appropriate would be to store numbers in an array and use built in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the minus sign:

```
    [~] $ # Creating and array with an arbitrary name:
    [~] $ array17=(-32 45 -45 -72)
    [~] $ # Calling all elements of the array and removing the first minus sign:
    [~] $ echo ${array17[*]/-}
    32 45 45 72
    [~] $
```